# MySql select joined rows that don't exists in third table

Tags: mysql, select, many-to-many

I'm having difficulties with creating a sql query that selects a joining of 2 tables where the relationship doesn't exists in a third table.

To be more specific I try to explain it with an example. 
I have a table member, form and member_form. 
When a member inserts an answer in the form, it's saved in the member_form table. 
The forms can be active, and have a deadline. 
So what I want is to return a result for each member and the form he still didn't fill in. But the form must be active, and deadline must be for example 2018-03-15.  I don't know the amount of members or forms. So I can't say from select * where member id is = x. 
This is needed to send a reminder mail to all the users that didn't fill in the form yet for a specific date.

```
member
id  |   name    |   email
--------------------------
1   |   Test    |   test@email.com
2   |   test2   |   test2@email.com
4   |   test4   |   test4@email.com
5   |   test5   |   test5@email.com
6   |   test6   |   test6@email.com
7   |   test7   |   test7@email.com


form
id  |   insert_date         |   deadline_date       |   active
---------------------------------------------------------------
1   |   2018-03-15 00:00:00 |   2018-03-15 00:00:00 |   1   
2   |   2018-02-10 00:00:00 |   2018-05-15 00:00:00 |   0   
3   |   2018-03-15 00:00:00 |   2018-03-15 00:00:00 |   1   
5   |   2018-03-15 00:00:00 |   2018-06-15 00:00:00 |   1   
6   |   2018-03-15 00:00:00 |   2018-05-15 00:00:00 |   1   
7   |   2018-03-15 00:00:00 |   2018-04-15 00:00:00 |   0       


member_form
member_id   |   form_id     |   answer
--------------------------------------
1           |   6           |   1
1           |   2           |   2
1           |   5           |   1
2           |   2           |   1
2           |   3           |   1
4           |   6           |   2
5           |   6           |   3
5           |   7           |   2
6           |   1           |   2
7           |   2           |   1


Result
member_id   |   name    |   email           |   form_id |   insert_date         |   deadline_date       |   active
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2           |   test2   |   test2@email.com |   6       |   2018-03-15 00:00:00 |   2018-05-15 00:00:00 |   1
6           |   test6   |   test6@email.com |   6       |   2018-03-15 00:00:00 |   2018-05-15 00:00:00 |   1
7           |   test7   |   test7@email.com |   6       |   2018-03-15 00:00:00 |   2018-05-15 00:00:00 |   1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM form AS f , member AS m WHERE f.deadline_date = '2018-05-15 00:00:00' AND f.active = 1 and !exists(select * FROM member_form AS amf WHERE amf.member_id = am.id And amf.form_id = af.id);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM Member m, Form f 
WHERE CONCAT(m.id,':',f.id) NOT IN
(SELECT CONCAT(mf.member_id, ':', mf.form_id) FROM Member_form mf)
AND f.deadline_date = '2018-05-15' 
AND f.active = 1
```

Comment: On first few trials this works also. But the answer from Max goes a little faster. 229 total, Query took 0.0041 sec vs 229 total, Query took 0.0031 sec. But thank you very much for helping with this problem